# CSS property to push element down if overlapped, remain top if not overlapped?

Tags: css

I have some dynamically generated items with the given `top` property. I would like:

1. If there is no element above an item or no overlap, it remains its `top` property.
2. If there are some items above that overlap, push them down until none of them overlap.

How could I achieve this `min-top` or `max-margin` like property?

[image]

```js
const button = document.querySelector("input");
button.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList = 'item';
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  item.style.top = height + 'px';
  item.innerText = 'Top ' + height
  container.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Add random item">
<div id="container" class="container">
  Container
</div>
```

Comment: There is no property for that. Absolute positioned elements are taken out of the normal layout flow, so they will overlap like this. You will need to handle this in your JavaScriot - keep track of what elements with what heights you added where, and then modify the position of the next element you're about to insert, accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use wrapper container for items and append new items inside it. You can position this new container absolute and give it properties `display: flex;flex-direction: column`;
Something like this

```
const button = document.querySelector("input");
button.addEventListener("click", addItem);

function addItem() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container-new');
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.classList = 'item';
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  item.style.top = height + 'px';
  item.innerText = 'Top ' + height
  container.appendChild(item);
}
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.containew-new {
position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 0px;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;  
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Add random item">
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="container-new" class="container-new">
  Container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the added items do not remain their order by `top` property.

Comment: sorry, misread you question from the start/ In this case you will need to recount every element position  in js.